# LINQ Query returns no results

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I am trying to run a linq query using EF on .NET 3.5 and this query should return a result but isn't.  I am wondering if I don't have it formatted correctly.

```
lret = IEnumerable<Place>
request.Category = long[]{1}
```

lret can have many categories

There is a place in the database that is assigned to CategoryId of 1

```
 lRet = lRet.Where(
    s => s.Categories.Any(
       t => request.Category.Contains(t.CategoryId)
    )
 );
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF 1 doesn't support `IEnumerable<T>.Contains()`. You need EF 4 for that.

Comment: Is there a similar way to do this using .NET 3.5?

Comment: Search this site for `BuildContainsExpression`